# Is the s in U.S.A. an /s/ or a /z/?

Tags: pronunciation

I believe English speakers tend to default to the sounded /z/, but the letter s in isolation is not sounded - it is an /s/, rather than a /z/.

How is it handled in an acronym, such as "U.S.A"?

Comment: It's the same thing on both sides of the Atlantic when speaking those letters. S is S. /s/. This is not some plural of a word like  house/houses.

Comment: @Lambie So it's not relaxed (bee sound) - it is not sounded. I'm not sure of the proper phonetic terms... It would be the same for the word 'yes'... The 's' is /s/.

Comment: Ok, it is just an s. A normal s sound as in reciting the alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phonetic term you're looking for is [**voiced**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)), not **sounded**.  The sound [s] is unvoiced, and the sound [z] is voiced.  That is, when you pronounce [z], your vocal folds vibrate; when you pronounce [s], they don't.

When pronouncing the abbreviation **U.S.A.** (yoo-ess-ay), English speakers use an **unvoiced** [s].

And really, it's not quite true that English speakers "tend to" voice the letter 's'.  It's common, but it's not a general rule and unfortunately, you just have to memorize which words have a voiced 's' and which don't.  For example, **usage** has an unvoiced [s], while **usable** has a voiced [z].  Why?  That's just the way it is.